# SQLをHTMLに表示する

Tags: html, sql

どこをみてもhtmlからsqlへの接続ができません

追記

htmlからのsqlへのinsert,sqlからのhtmlへの表示がしたいです

Comment: 「できない」であるなら、何か実際に試した手順だったりの情報をもう少し詳しく書いた方が伝わりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

HTML が何かプログラム言語のようにふるまう代物で HTML ファイルがあればそこから自動的にデーターベースに接続される / できるかの如く思っているように見える質問文ですね。実際は HTML はただのテキストで、その中で部分部分に意味づけができるだけのものです。

あなたがやりたいことは「動的 HTML 生成」ってやつでしょう。 Web Server 上のプログラムがデーターベースからデータを取り出しそれを HTML 形式に変換して読者に届けるとか、逆に読者からもらったデータをそのプログラムが安全にデーターベースに登録するとか。そういう風に世の中の掲示板だのブログだのは実装されています。ここ stackoverflow も例外ではありません。

この Web ユーザーからは見えない陰でこっそり動いているプログラムはいろんなプログラム言語で書くことができます。 [c](/questions/tagged/c) でも [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) でも [php](/questions/tagged/php) でも [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) でもそのほかの言語でも作ることができます。プログラムですから、あなたやオイラが自作してもいいんですけど、すでにあるものを使うほうが手早そうです。とりあえずは [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) とか調べてみるとよいのでは？

Comment: phpでの接続を試みてます

Comment: なら最初から「 php でデータベースに接続して HTML を作りたい」と質問すればいいんですよ（それならマイナス評価もつかないはず）まあつく回答は同じで「わざわざ自作してセキュリティ的脆弱性を出すくらいなら出来合いの wordpress でも※※※でも△△△でも使うことを検討してください」になりそうですけど。

Comment: wordpressはテーマで制約されてしまうので

Comment: その辺の事情はオイラ（やほかの読者）の知ったことではないので何とも言えません。 wordpress が気に入らないなら別のブログ・掲示板ソフトを試せばいいんですよ。自分で作るのは最終手段（試した全部が気に入らなかったとき）で。とりあえず検索したら https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88 こんなの出ましたけど。

Comment: ありがとうございます ただ自分（独自）のデータをsqlに組み込んでそれを表示したいというのもあるので己でいきたいという所存です

Comment: それならばそれで全く問題なくて、疑問点とかあればぜひ stackoverflow を活用してください。これがわからない→こうすればいい、は質疑応答として好まれます。きっとプラス評価がバンバンつきますよ。ただし、今のこの質問文みたいに「技術的におかしい質問」は論外です。あなたにとってはおかしくなくても、第三者読者が読んだら「コイツ何言ってんだ」（ぜんぜんわかってないから回答しても無駄にしかならない）と思わせるような質問は技術者の集まる場ではダメです。

Comment: ご叱咤ありがとうございます そうですね それはこちらとしても承知しています ただいまそこまで冗長をやっていられないので短縮しました 必要であれば追記します

Comment: （オイラの正直な感想：何言ってんだこいつ）上司に質問するときも事情説明を短縮しますか？オイラならそんな間抜けな部下は評価下げます（＝給料下げます）。質問を手抜きする＝答えが得られないだけなので、手抜きしたいならどうぞご自由に。あなたにとっても読者にとっても時間の無駄に終わるでしょうけど。

Comment: そうですね それは書いてておもいました ただコードを一旦貼ってただしく表示されなかったという経緯もあります

Comment: また ひとつせっかくなのでご存知でしたらお聞きしたいのですがwordpressのサイドバーのデータはsqlにどう組まれているとおもいますか？ tableですか？columnですか？

Comment: それこそ正しい技術的質問なので新規スレッドでどうぞ